# How to show/hide Actionbar when clicked on

Tags: android, android-actionbar, show-hide

When the user clicks anywhere on the screen, I want the Actionbar to hide and when pressed again it should reappear.

I know there is something called actionbar.hide(); and show, but can you please help me how to implement it? :)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just [hide()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#hide%28%29):

```
getActionBar().hide();
```

when you want to hide it, and use [show()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#show%28%29):

```
getActionBar().show()
```

when you want to show it. That's about it.

Remember that if you're using [View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN), this will not work properly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :) But how can u hide it when you press anywhere on the screen?

Comment: @ymerdrengene Override onTouch()

Comment: @RaghavSood There is lag on calling show()/hide() is called. Can this be avoided?

Answer (score 1):

Try this. you have here the possibility to call hide or show method and according to your proposal

```
public class AbstractActivity Activity {

   private boolean showActions = false;


   @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

      ActionBar bar = getSupportActionBar();
      if (bar != null) {
         bar.setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
         bar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
      }
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
      return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }

   @Override
   public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
      int id = item.getItemId();
      switch (id) {
      case android.R.id.home:

         return true;
      default:
         // Nothing to do here
         return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
      }
   }

   private void handleActionBarTitle(boolean show) {
      ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
      if (actionBar == null) {
         return;
      }
      actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(show);
   }


   protected void disableActions() {
      this.showActions = false;
   }

   protected void enableActions() {
      this.showActions = true;
   }

   protected void hideActionBarTitle() {
      handleActionBarTitle(false);
   }

   protected boolean showActions() {
      return showActions;
   }

   protected void showActionTitle() {
      handleActionBarTitle(true);
   }
```

Your activity just need to extends this AbstractActivity

Comment: I think my question was unclear. Instead of showing/hiding the actionbar i ment if you could go "fullscrean-mode" which i found out how to do it.