# Hiding ActionBar Tabs in Android

Tags: android

I'm facing the problem hiding the actionBar tabs. I want to create the actionBar tabs when the application loads and hide, but when I click the actionbar menu icon it should show. SetNavigationMode makes application unresponsive.Any help

Comment: Is it the same as this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327208/how-to-show-hide-actionbar-when-clicked-on

Answer (score 0):

It should work :

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```