# Hide action bar on soft keyboard popup in fragment

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I want to hide action bar on soft keyboard popup. I have used the code the following code to get the result. But when i want to go back, the app crashes. I have included in which line i am getting the error also. Please guide me through this.

Thanks in advance.

private void createView() {

```
    mRootView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {

            Rect rect = new Rect();
            //rect will be populated with the coordinates of your view that area still visible.

            mRootView.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(rect);
            int heightDiff = mRootView.getRootView().getHeight() - (rect.bottom - rect.top);

            if (heightDiff > 100) {

                // if more than 100 pixels, its probably a keyboard...
                //keyboard visible
                mBinding.healthRecordContainer.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().hide();

            } else {

                //keyboard not visible
                mBinding.healthRecordContainer.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().show(); // app crashes
            } //java.lang.NullPointerException
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Try that: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327208/how-to-show-hide-actionbar-when-clicked-on](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15327208/how-to-show-hide-actionbar-when-clicked-on)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code. Then app wont crash.

```
Activity activity = getActivity();

if (activity instanceof ActionBarActivity) {

    ActionBarActivity actionBarActivity = (ActionBarActivity) activity;

    ActionBar actionBar = actionBarActivity.getSupportActionBar();

    if (actionBar != null) {
        actionBar.hide();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do only one thing in your manifest where you have declared your activity.
for e.g.

```
<activity
            android:name=".Your Activity here"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize"
            >
        </activity>
```

Comment: Is this to hide the soft keyboard?